# Adobe Flex delayed observer for auto-complete TextInput

Tags: apache-flex

Does anyone know if there is a Flex 3 or Flex 4 equivalent to the JQuery DelayedObserver?

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-utils/wiki/DelayedObserver

If not, how could we go about implementing it in Flex?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the component does exactly and I couldn't find an actual running sample anywhere via Google.  If you're looking to delay a call you can use a [Timer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html?filter_coldfusion=9&filter_flex=3&filter_flashplayer=10&filter_air=1.5) or [CallLater](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=layoutperformance_12.html).

If you're looking for an AutoComplete component, I am prone to recommend my own [AutoComplete Component](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductHome&productID=19).  The Flex 4 / Spark version is available free, although does not have the API breadth that the Flex 3 MX version does.

Comment: Maybe I should be more specific... I want an AutoComplete component which only fires web service HTTP requests every n characters (or better yet every n milliseconds) where n is configurable.

Comment: That is an interesting feature.  You could simulate every either approach with the Flextras AutoCompleteComboBox by setting the AutoCompleteRemoteData property to true; then canceling the filtering event.  A sample is here: https://www.flextras.com/AutoCompleteComboBox/Samples/DBFilter/ .  Right click for the source code.  You'd have to change the sample to use a timer or keep track of the character count.  I've added that feature to "idea list" but don't expect a native implementation anytime soon.